# How to move a text from an input field to another by pressing a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm new in javascript so I'm sorry if I  my question is silly
I am suppodsed to make a dive where there would be two input fields and a button. When you press the button the text that is written in first field must move to the second one. This is what I have done:

```js
<script>
function myfunction(){
 var fp= document.forms["fora"];
  fp.elements[1].innerHTML=fp.element[0].value;
  fp.elements[0].value="";
  
}




</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>Project 2 </title>



</head>


<body>


 <div>
  <form id=fora>
   First phrase:<br>
   <input type="text"  name="first phrase" >
   <br>
   Second phase:<br>
   <input  type="text" name="second phrase">
   

  </form> 
  <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">push me
   </button>
  <buttom>
  </button>

 </div>
 <p id="intro"></p>

</body>


</html>
```

Has anyone any idea what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `innerHTML` to `value`. And there is a typo `fp.element` (missing `s` , should be `fp.elements`)

```
var fp= document.forms["fora"];
    fp.elements[1].value=fp.elements[0].value;
    fp.elements[0].value="";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!  I wasted so much time on this . May I ask you if you are a linux user which text editor you use? Cause I use gedit and i would like to show my if I have typos. Thanks again

Comment: This time it was gedit. :) But usually it's phpstorm or eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to read and set the values of the inputs based on the names:

```
function myfunction(){
        document.getElementsByName("second phrase")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("first phrase")[0].value;
        document.getElementsByName("first phrase")[0].value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
fp.elements[1].innerHTML=fp.element[0].value;
```

to

```
fp.elements[1].value = fp.elements[0].value;
```

```js
function myfunction(){
    var fp= document.forms["fora"];
    fp.elements[1].value = fp.elements[0].value;
    fp.elements[0].value = "";
}
```

```html
<form name="fora">
    First phrase:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstPhrase" ><br>
    Second phase:<br>
    <input type="text" name="secondPhrase">
</form> 
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">push me</button>
```